# My app got rejected because of mature mopub Ad, What type of IAB category is an ad like this?

Tags: google-play, ads, google-play-console, mopub

The most recent update to my app on Google Play was rejected because the app "contains ad content that is not appropriate for children".
[App update rejected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjt8q.png)

More specifically it was rejected because the app is rated 3+ but it showed an ad for Bigo Live, a social app rated 12+.
[Bigo Live ad in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFKAj.png)

I know the solution is to block ads of this kind using MoPub Content Blocking. But the question is, what IAB category does it fall under?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the IAB category of an individual advert is not a software development question as defined in the [help], so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Content Blocking](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/ui/content-blocking/) in mopub and block this app:

> Content blocking at the account level is the one-stop place to apply advertising filters across your account. Here, you can block advertiser URLs, install ads for specific apps, and general ad categories across all the apps in your account. You can always override these account-wide settings at the app level if you want to set unique content filters for individual apps.

[image: screenshot]

**Also**, if you app is not targeted toward kids you can got to `Google Play Console` > `App Content` > `Target audience and content` > and chose higher `target age`

[image: google play console screen]